# How can I fix my code for my discord bot?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot to spam @everyone and troll my friends, but I can't seem to get it to loop. What am I doing wrong?

```html
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    try {
                message.channel.send('@everyone listen to this man.');
                message.delete(1000);
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
            }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "servernotgood",
    desc: "Mentions everyone?.",
    personalThoughts: "Its a command that mentions everyone.)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't fix what you did but i can give you about what you want.

```
setInterval(() => { 
   message.channel.send("@everyone listen to this man.");
   message.delete(1000); //if you want the message get deleted.
},1500);
```